# Minimisation problem turned into Maximisation

Tags: mathematical-economics, utility, optimization, lagrangian

My course always converts minimisation problems into maximisation. They given the following reason as outlined in the problem below.

> $Min\; P_xx + P_yy \; s.t. \; u(x,y) \le x^{\frac{1}{2}} + y$
>
> - "***In order to apply the Kuhn-Tucker theorem we can rewrite this problem as***"

They would write it as:

$Max\; -(P_xx + P_yy) \; s.t. \; -u(x,y) \ge -(x^{\frac{1}{2}} + y)$

1. As far as i'm aware it's not strictly necessary to do this, so long as our constraint and objective function are both convex (i.e. our Lagrangian is convex), then the KKT / Lagrange technique will find a minimum, just as it would find a maximum, and through duality, these will be the same value. So why the emphasis? I have suspicion that it could be to do with a subtle point regarding non-negativity constraints that they haven't elaborated.

**Non negativity constraints:** Assuming the possibility of $y = 0$ I have written the problem below both as a maximisation and a minimisation:

Max: $L(,x,t,λ) = -(P_xx + P_yy)  - λ[(\bar{u} -(x^{\frac{1}{2}} + y)] + μy$
Min: $L(,x,t,λ) = (P_xx + P_yy)  + λ[(\bar{u} -(x^{\frac{1}{2}} + y)] - μy$

Taking the FOC with respect to y from the Maximisation problem we get:

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial y} = -P_yy  + λ + m \le 0$ Which as $μ \ge 0$ implies $\frac{\partial L}{\partial y} = -P_yy  + λ \le 0$

And now here is my problem, taking the FOC with a respect to the Minimisation problem we get.

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial y} = P_yy  - λ - μ \le 0$

I believe that the gap in my knowledge is that actually when we have a minimisation problem, and are testing a binding non-negativity constraint i.e. boundary solution on the axis, then the inequality in the FOC becomes $\ge 0$

I.e. It should be: $\frac{\partial L}{\partial y} = P_yy  - λ - μ \ge 0$

This is the only way i can get it to make sense otherwise the two versions are giving different results.  This problem goes unnoticed when it's equality contained. And because my course has never written the problem formally as a minimisation problem i haven't been able to see what happens in this boundary case.

if i am write can someone explain some economic / mathematical intuition behind the  $\ge 0$.

Thanks!