# Technology Parameter In Converted Minimisation Problem

Tags: mathematical-economics, production-function, optimization, technology, lagrangian

**Question:**

I want to understand what's going on with respect to the technology parameter $A$ when i convert this minimisation problem into a maximisation problem. The issue is only revealed when i use the envelope theorem to differentiate the Lagrangian with respect to $A$ at the optimal point.

when i take $\frac{\partial L}{\partial A}|_{(k,l) = (k_c,l_c)}$

**I get the wrong sign when i have converted the minimisation problem into a maximisation problem.**

- I wan't to understand the intuition of what's happening here, and what this error means for the underlying relationship between the corresponding, min, max problems.

Note: I have stated that A is a technology parameter. I assume for this to make sense we should have $A > 1$?

**Context:**

Say we want to Minimise costs $rk + wl \; s.t. Q = (k^{\frac{1}{p}} + Al^{\frac{1}{p}})^p$ a standard CES production function.

Below i give the Lagrangian for the minimisation problem, or the representative maximisation problem (Which my course often tells me to use instead):

- Min $L(k, l , λ) = rk + wl + λ[Q - (k^{\frac{1}{p}} + Al^{\frac{1}{p}})^p]$
- Max $L(k, l , λ) = -(rk + wl) - λ[Q - (k^{\frac{1}{p}} + Al^{\frac{1}{p}})^p]$

Now finding the Compensated factor demands, the cost function etc. All of it works out fine in the Maximisation case.

The issues comes when i want to understand how a "*Small Change in A affects the optimal solution*" take: $\frac{\partial L}{\partial A}|_{(k,l) = (k_c,l_c)}$

With the minimisation Lagrangian we get the correct answer which is: $-\frac{w}{A}pl_c$

With the maximisation Lagrangian we get the wrong sign i.e.
$\frac{w}{A}pl_c$

This is perhaps related to a [previous question of mine](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/55496/minimisation-problem-turned-into-maximisation) regarding converting min to max and vice versa.